# Возможно ли добавление виджета по имени объекта?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlayout, findchildren, objectname

Подскажите, как возможно в *PyQt5* что-либо сделать (например добавить в макет) по имени объекта, установленным:

```
widget.setObjectName("widget_name")
```

На просторах SO нашел: `QObject.findChild(arg__1[, arg__2=""])` 
и `QApplication.focusWidget()`. Но, если я правильно понял, то это не то, что мне нужно. Необходимо манипулировать объектом по его имени.

Возможно ли это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что `findChild`, это то, что вам должно помочь.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centrawidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centrawidget)        
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centrawidget)
        
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(
            placeholderText="Введите име объекта")
        
        self.pushButton = QPushButton("Добавить объект в Layout") 
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btn_clicked)    

        for i in range(7): 
            name = f"label_{i}"
            label = QLabel(name, self)
            label.setObjectName(name)
            label.move(0, -80)
            
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        
    def btn_clicked(self):   
        label = self.findChild(QLabel, self.lineEdit.text())
        if label:
            label.setText(f'Это label с именем объкта: '
                f'<b>{label.objectName()}</b>')
            self.layout.insertWidget(0, label)
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, это работает как нужно. Спасибо, видимо не разобрался не до конца.

Comment: @Rett_oo пожалуйста.